# Cognos Analytics - Report does not load when combining two dimensions

Tags: cognos, cognos-bi, cognos-11

If I want to use two dimensions in a crosstab, the report starts to process (no errors) but does not finish to load (after 30 minutes). When I use the dimension individually the report is ready after 30 to 60 seconds. Both Dimensions have a 1 to 1 (Dimension) to 1 to N (fact table) relationship modelled in Cognos Framework Manager. If I run the generated MDX/SQL directly in the database the query is running indefinitely as well...

Does anyone have an idea why this could happen?

Any help appreciated!

Comment: How much in conformance to best practices is your model?

Dimensions just relational objects or or DMR?  

If DMR, what happens if you use the underlying relational objects in a crosstab? List?  

What happens if you try the report as a list?

What happens if you put the fact and the two keys in the fact table which represent the dimensions into a crosstab ? I.e. controlling for the dimensions.

How many rows in each of the tables?

How many members?

What are the keys? Have you done anything funky in the relationship expressions?

What settings do you have on the report?

Comment: What sort of resources do you have on your server?

There might be more questions coming once I think of them and if I get more information.

Comment: Examine the group by statement.  
Also see if the query is it trying to do a full outer join with a coalesce (if so, it is trying to stitch two facts, meaning you may have more than one fact in the model)?

In the model make sure the nothing is trying to aggregate/be treated like a fact except for that one metric you have.

Comment: Also, are you using determinants?  If so, that may hint at where the issue is

Answer (score 0):

Share the generated MDX/SQL with your data architect and/or database administrator.  They should be able to tell you what is wrong with the relationships in your model.